# Not able to run specific terminal commands from java program(Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, exec, processbuilder

Using ProcessBuilder in JAVA I am able to run simple terminal commands like ls,pwd,echo etc..etc...
But following code is getting terminated , don't know why??

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p = r.exec("echo 'T W O N E I G H T' | /home/saj/g2p/mosesdecoder-master/bin/moses -f /home/saj/g2p/working/binarised-model/moses.ini");
    p.waitFor();

    BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line = "";
    while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) 
    {
      System.out.println(line);
    } 
}
```

This command works perfectly from terminal and takes around 15 seconds to run and gives output.
I have gone through similar topics on stackoverflow but did not found any help.
Please help in this regard.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `But following code is getting terminated` ... what is the exception or error you are getting?

Answer (score 2):

Refer this code this may help u....use bash.Just replace your command with echo command

ProcessBuilder b = new ProcessBuilder("bash","-c","echo abc");

```
    Process termProc = null;

    try {
        termProc = b.start();
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
        InputStreamReader(termProc.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
        InputStreamReader(termProc.getErrorStream()));

        String s = null;
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            System.out.println(s);


         }
        while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) 
        {

            System.out.println(s);

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider monitoring both the InputStream and ErrorStream. Chances are that the output is probably getting written to the ErrorStream and that's why you don't see anything getting displayed.

[Here's a good example](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=4) from Javaworld regarding some of the common pitfalls of Runtime.exec() and how to go about using it.

---

I missed it at the first look at your code but here's a hint to what you might be doing wrong:

> Because some native platforms only provide limited buffer size for
>   standard input and output streams, failure to promptly write the input
>   stream or read the output stream of the subprocess may cause the
>   subprocess to block, and even deadlock.

Consider an update to your code along these lines:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p = r.exec("echo 'T W O N E I G H T' | /home/saj/g2p/mosesdecoder-master/bin/moses -f /home/saj/g2p/working/binarised-model/moses.ini");

    BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line = "";
    while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) 
    {
      System.out.println(line);
    } 

    BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
    String line = "";
    while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) 
    {
      System.out.println(line);
    } 

    p.waitFor();
}
```

**Note:** I would suggest creating threads to handle displaying your output from inputstream and errorstream as in the example link that I posted above.

Comment: ok I will try what you are saying... but why it is getting terminated in 2-3 seconds.. where it is supposed to run ~15 seconds.

Comment: @saj1919: well, I would guess that you're running into some kind of exception and that's why the process isn't behaving the way you want it to. One of the reasons why I suggested that you monitor the error stream as well

Comment: Now I tried this but still same result I am getting.. termination                                                                         b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
  line = "";
  while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) 
  {
    System.out.println(line);
  }

Comment: @saj1919: can you post your updated code? and when you say termination, do you come across any kind of exception?

Comment: I am getting this output...=> 'T W O N E I G H T' | /home/saj/g2p/mosesdecoder-master/bin/moses -f /home/saj/g2p/working/binarised-model/moses.ini
No Exceptions !!

Comment: It is still not working... but I figured out this thing. echo and concatenation may not be working. Because "echo 'home/saj/'| ls" is also terminating. So I tried my command without echo... => /home/saj/g2p/mosesdecoder-master/bin/moses -f /home/saj/g2p/working/binarised-model/moses.ini 'T W O N E I G H T'           It runs forever.. Can you tell me how to write my command correctly..